# High engine temperature

Tags: engine, nissan, cooling, micra

I have used a Nissan Micra K12 1.0(CR10DE) that I've bought recently. It is running hot all the time no matter I'm driving it or not. I have checked the thermostat and found it removed, before that I took it for diagnostics scan due to hard starting and high fuel consumption and I was told to replace the crankshaft position sensor (replaced with no positive effect). What is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean with "t is running hot all the time no matter I'm driving it or not"? The temp gauge is on hot even if the dash is on but the engine is off or just on idle?

Comment: sorry my English is not very good. every engine has it's normal operating temp by design, a good engine operator/driver can differentiate between a normal and abnormal operating temps.....I know from my experience that my micra engine is running hot......abnormal for an engine radiator cooling fan to run for long time even the engine idle.

Comment: My car runs the radiator cooling fan for a long time even after I shut off the engine. Are you sure you have a problem, or maybe you are just unused to the Micra?

Comment: Coolant temp sensor ?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, your thermostat was removed? In that case, have a new one installed.

Aside from that, there could be lots of reasons for your engine running hot:

- A blockage in the cooling system, e.g. if there's something blocking the radiator or one of the pipes have collapsed.
- not enough coolant.
- losing pressure in the cooling system, e.g. if there's a leaking pipe.
- **a broken waterpump** - this is my guess. The waterpump pumps coolant around the engine. If it's broken, there won't be any flow.
- the engine is running too lean (not getting enough fuel)
- the thermostat stays closed. Not your problem, but maybe for someone else.
- Not enough oil or the wrong type of oil.

Comment: Thanks Juann,installing new one will not resolve my problem.....cause I know the engine is running hot....that is why thermostat was removed either by previous owner or by the mechanic.....they did not find the problem and they went for easy fix...removing thermostat.

Comment: Of course. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hi Juann,thanks for the update.....engine oil level & type,water pump,cooling system pressure and coolant level all checked and found O.K,one thing I forgot to mention....the engine was scanned and crankshaft sensor was found to be defective,replaced it with new one but no changes on fuel consumption,engine temperature & and power loss......engine maybe running rich,can this cause the problem?

Comment: Running rich won't make it run hotter, but it would explain your poor consumption and loss of power. The Crank sensor would cause the ignition timing to be wrong, so consumption would suffer, but running rich has a cooling effect. How hot is the engine running anyway? Engines optimised for efficiency and emissions run quite hot. Mine actually runs best at 99 Celsius, which is boiling point for water.

Comment: I'm not sure if it was optimized for efficiency or emission...just bought it recently from UK,how can I find out if it was optimized?.....mine is 97+ Celsius...The engine looks like the timing chain was replaced....it has gasket maker on timing cover. I know wrong timing can also cause the engine to run hotter....do you have an idea how the intake valve timing control solenoid valve works on nissan micra cr10de engine.....?

Comment: Nope. My knowledge is limit to Vauxhall/Opel engines. I assume it's basically the same thing though. If you're still losing power, then maybe someone needs to take a look at your timing issues first. Maybe the camshafts weren't aligned properly when the timing chain was replaced.

Comment: I agree with you on getting it checked for ignition  timing first......i'll update you when this is done.

Answer (score 1):

One of the simpliest solutions is to check coolant route:

1. There can be air in hoses, add some coolant while revving engine (it will pump liquid and you can fill air with a liquid)
2. Check tubes for bend, it can stop liquid flow

Not sure crank sensor can cause heat, but o2 sensor can. If your AFR is lean it can produce more heat. Anyway, please provide exact coolant temp and environment temp, as if you are in Africa then even boiling water in radiator is ok ;)

Comment: BTW, to check flow, you can disconnect coolant hose and try to crank engine. If pump and tubes are ok, liquid will spread through tube.

Comment: BTW2: as Juann mentioned, oil can also cause heat, please check oil level and make sure it is not old.

Answer (score 1):

The removal of the thermostat on an engine will cause poor circulation of the coolant and cause overheating on its own, especially at the furthest cylinders. On the Nissan K12 the timing chains have always have had a tendency to stretch. (They are a simple single link chain.) This may be contributing to a wrong diagnosis of the crankshaft sensor. Your cooling system needs to be professionally flow checked, to include a flow check on the radiator.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the overheating may be due to absence of a thermostat which was removed. But how about the the high idling Can it also cause overheating of an engine?